# Parameterized Custom Label

Tags: customlabel

Is there a way to parameterize a custom label? Example:

Label name: `MyTestLabel`

Label value: `Thank you, {0}, for your feedback.`

Then in Apex, do something like this:

```
String name = 'John';
String label = Label.MyTestLabel;
String value = String.valueOf(label, name);
```

The idea being that the `value` variable would now hold "`Thank you, John, for your feedback.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this using the [String.format()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm) method which can provide parameter substitution on your label. The second parameter to this method is a List type and contains your parameters to be substituted.

```
Label name: MyTestLabel
Label value: Thank you, {0}, for your feedback.


List<String> parameters = new List<String>();
parameters.add('John');

String label = Label.MyTestLabel;
String value = String.format(label, parameters);
```

You can do it in one line like this as well:

```
string.format(Label.MyTestLabel, new String[]{'John'});
string.format(Label.MyTestLabel, new List<String>{'John'});
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure why I did not put two and two together on this. It worked perfectly.

Comment: @JohnGaughan glad you got it worked out!