# Custom Label: Passing Parameter

Tags: apex, customlabel

I have looked at this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40042/parameterized-custom-label) but this is not working and I have the exact same requirement where I will have to pass the parameter to a custom label

```
string parameter = 'this is a test';
string label =  System.Label.test;
String value = String.format(label, parameter); 
System.debug('//' + value);
```

Here is the error:

> Variable does not exist: String

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a List to send 'parameter'

```
String value = String.format(label, new List<String>{ parameter });
```

Comment: ah ha got it...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like some SFDC error messages are not clear/helpful enough :P. A `String.format(String, String) method doesn't exist` would be more accurate I think.